# "Create new project platforms" checkbox is disabled

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I need to change "Any CPU" to x32. But when I open the "New Solution Platform" window the "Create new project platforms" check box appears disabled.

How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why you are doing it like this, so here is how I normally set it up:

1. Create new solution with default settings.
2. Change platform to `x86` via `Project` properties / `Compile` tab / `Advanced Compile Options...` button in the bottom / `Target CPU` dropdown.

[image]